# Issue Parsing Date Showing Incorrect Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-parsing

I have a JS function that generates today date:

```js
function GetDate(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    alert(today);

    return today;  // 13/03/2021
}
```

This function returns `13/03/2021`

I pass it on to Server Side Code and do this :

```cs
DateTime dateToday = DateTime.ParseExact(cdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"));
emailCopy = emailCopy.Replace("{date}", dateToday.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
```

However here it puts the date as `12 March 2021`

Why is it doing that? The date going in is clearly `13/03/2021`. Also in next line I pass this date to be added to SQL Server Table:

```cs
dateToday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

And the date added to the database is also correct : `2021-03-13.`

Comment: Maybe i'm reading this wrong, but you are wondering why `dateToday.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")` outputs `12 March 2021`? This is a very confusing question and you should make it more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Andy yes .. that is the question ..I mean i clearly say date from JS is 13/03/2021 , But on server side it makes it 12 when i do the conversion.

Comment: It's right in the format -- that's why it's confusing. `dd MMMM yyyy` is outputting `12 March 2021` -- and you don't get why it's doing that? What don't you get about it? What's `dd MMMM yyyy` *supposed* to output?

Comment: 13 March 2021..

Comment: oh i see -- the *day* is off. I thought you were taking crazy pills.

Comment: :D up since almost 5 am  so no need for pills :D

Comment: Just to be clear, you're comparing code in JavaScript that isn't timezone aware with code in C# that is... and I suspect that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: @Powerlord not comparing i am passing js string over and  assuming it will show me the same date time object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `DateTime` object, but only set the date part of it, this sets the time to 00:00:00 (midnight). This is in GMT. So when you format the date it takes the date you set at midnight, and converts it to your time zone, which is actually the day before.

You can fix this by doing this "kludge":

```cs
var now = DateTime.Now;
var adjusted = new DateTime(
    dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month, dateToday.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
var final = adjusted.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

There may be a better way to do this, though.

> ETA

You should consider using JavaScript's `Date.toISOString()` instead of just sending the date. Then in C#, use `Convert.ToDateTime()` to parse it. That uses UTC and you are guaranteed to get the exact time that the client machine generated the date.

Comment: But i want to take the date on client Pc that is why the JS to pass date to server side code

Comment: @confusedMind -- awesome! Glad to hear it